# Secret component to make spray dough

Tags: dough

Is there any kind of dough that can be sprayed to make it any form and extra thin?

**EDIT:** I mean that dough was prepared with some liquid fast evaporated component to make it available for spraying.

Comment: Define what you qualify as 'dough'.  What you're describing would likely be called a 'batter', and even then, I don't know if there are any that could be necessarily sprayed (without customized equipment)

Comment: @Joe- Agreed.  I think even a batter would be too lumpy/thick for most sprayers.

Comment: most doughs / batters have flour in them, which needs to be cooked or tastes like raw flour.  You *might* be able to get a pannekoeken or other crepe batter thin enough for what you're trying, but you'd still have to cook it.  For something that comes out crisper and holds it shape, look to pizzelle or waffle cone recipes (although for those, you typically heat from both sides, so still might not be what you're looking for).  As for the actual spraying ... you might be able to use a paint sprayer with tips for thicker primers, but I doubt it'd be food-safe.

Comment: Depends... [Can you play with madness?](http://www.batterblaster.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I have never even heard of spray dough, but you could make a filo dough roll it out thin with a pasta machine and drape it over a shape and then attempt to bake it as long as the shape can withstand the heat. Or you could let the dough dry a bit and it may retain its shape after you pull the mold out for baking. Any decent bread dough recipe *should* work as long as the gluten content is high enough to withstand the pasta machine and molding process. Although you could take a paper mache approach and use thin dough strips.

Maybe if you can tell us more about what your end product should be we can help you get there.

Answer (score 1):

Spraying will not work with a flower based dough. The thinnest you'll get a flower dough without it falling apart instantly is using a filo recipe. The reason for this is that [gluten need to be formed by kneading](http://www.howtodothings.com/food-drink/the-chemistry-of-bread-making) to keep the structure together.

Batters work differently, they rely on proteïnes to keep their structure. If you look carefully at recipes for very thin crepes you'll notice that these contain more eggs. Even the thinnest crepe I ever got was not nearly as thin as you can get filo dough, but I never went for extreme proteïne content because I favor taste over presentation.

If your structure needs to be thinner than what you can do with filo, you could experiment with pure egg white, slowly baked on non-stick surfaces. I've had some interesting accidents with egg white, so I know that in theory you can get it extremely thin. It will be much more delicate than filo dough though, so you should be prepared for some frustration...

I guess that you don't need a sprayer for egg white, because you can apply it with a brush and it will spread evenly on its own.

Good luck, and take some pictures when you succeed!

Answer (score 1):

There's a pancake batter in a can that is sprayed, so this isn't impossible for batters; by most definitions of dough, however, you're talking about something that's solid. Spraying a solid would surely require a pretty substantial amount of force, probably on the order of repeated firings of a shotgun.

Industrially-produced panko or breadcrumbs can be made by either spraying a batter or extruding a dough and cooking it on a hot surface or in a microwave. There are some photos on http://www.oshikiri.com/products/line/crumb.html that describe one process (text in Japanese).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into a milieu feuilles recipe or filo dough, I'm not certain your application is the means to your end.